# Oracle Apex 5: Validation not working with submit button?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a process , a branch (to redirect page after button submitted) and validations. The process will insert into the table. The validations should work to clarify everything is A-Okay. Unfortunately, the validation isn't working when I submit the page. What could the reason be?

Thank you.

Comment: There's really not a lot of information in your question to base an answer on.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. I had a branch that redirected to another page, before validation and processing. So I clicked After Processing on the Branch, which meant it will activate after the validation and processes. Thanks all.